# How can we enable an audible alert for a new call?

Tags: slack

In Slack, when a new call starts in my team's stand-up meeting channel that I'm expected to join, I don't hear anything. The call object appears in the channel as a kind of message, with the Join button, but its appearance doesn't make a sound. Someone has to send me a message to get my attention, which works because that generates an audible notification.

I see in the Slack settings that it's possible to enable notifications for all messages, which looks like it might work, but I don't want to receive notifications for all messages. Certainly not across all channels.

Is there some solution for this? "Alert me if a call starts in channel " type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are per-channel preferences where a notification for every new message an be requested just for one channel. In a dedicated channel that is for stand-up calls and related chat, that seems to be good enough.